# populate drop down list and display on screen?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
//asp
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGroups" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>

//code behind
 protected void SelectAccessLevel()
        {
            List<string> ADGroups = new List<string>();
            ADGroups.Add("Group1");
            ADGroups.Add("Group2");
            ADGroups.Add("Group3");

            ddlGroups.DataSource = ADGroups;
            ddlGroups.DataBind();
        }
```

Create a drop down list in ascx page, bind to list in code behind and display on screen. Nothing displays in DD on screen..as to why? is it correct to bind the drop down or do I need to create another dd in code behind it to that?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Where you are calling this method? And BTW, it will bind the dropdown correctly, with text & value both set to whatever value you have in list.

Comment: Are you calling SelectAccessLevel in Load event of user control? And SelectAccessLevel  should be in ascx codebehind.

Comment: ddlGroup.DataTextField and ddlGroup.DataValueField needs to be added after ddlGroup.DataSource. Try it.

Comment: Have you registered your user control to a web page using Register directive? Do you see the unpopulated drop down list on the web page?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I usually (whenever I want them to be HARD CODED in the code) fill them like this:

```
ListItem li = new ListItem("Group 1", "1");
ListItem li2 = new ListItem("Group 2", "2");
ddlGroups.Items.Add(li);
ddlGroups.Items.Add(li2);
```

And well... yeah, that's it.